# Constant 'label' used before being initialized

Tags: swift, uilabel

The one which I am working on is on optional binding. I am unwrapping label which is of type `UILabel?` by using `if let`. I am trying to put my date string in the label. But I am getting this error:

> Constant 'label' used before being initialized

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFtWF.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code as text, not as a picture. Pictures can't be referenced or searched.

Comment: FYI - your date format is incorrect. Change `YYYY` to `yyyy`. They seem similar and they give the same result in most cases but you really never want `YYYY`. Always use `yyyy` for the year.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you the issue. The `label` variable has been declared but it has not been initialized. It has no value yet.

The line:

```
let label: UILabel?
```

doesn't make much sense. You've used `let` which means its value can't ever be changed. But you have not given it a value.

It's unclear what you want done with `label`.

Given your current code, `label` has no use.

At a minimum, just to get your code to compile, you can change it to:

```
let label: UILabel? = nil
```

While this fixes the error is pointless because then it can only ever be nil and you will never have an actual label.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy , Can you tell me if there is any possibility of getting the date into the label.

Comment: There is no label. That's the problem. You really need something like `let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(proper stuff here))` and then any other setup of the label. Then you can set its `text` property.